# Best way to retrieve addresses using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider I have two table named as **addresses** and **customers** showed in the code below.

**Customer Table:**

> **`customer_id, email_address, password, first_name, last_name, shipping_address_id, billing_address_id`**

**Addresses Table:**

> **`address table with fields as address_id, customer_id, line1, line2, city, state, zip_code, phone, disabled`**

What I need to get is both billing and shipping address based on customer id.

**Something like:**

```
first_name | last_name | billing_line_1 | billing_line_2 | billing_state | billing_zip_code | billing_phone | shipping_line_1 | shipping_line_2 | shipping_city | shipping_city | shipping_state | shipping_zip_code | shipping_phone
```

I am using something like:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, addresses.line1 ,addresses.line2 
FROM `addresses`INNER JOIN customers 
on addresses.address_id = customers.customer_id
```

**My Question is:**

> How can I label the same field twice as **billing_line_1** and **shipping_line_1**?

**UPDATE:**

Based on join it returns both addresses as same if I repeat field in select statement while both shipping and billing address are stored separately based on address_id.

Comment: Use aliases with `AS` keyword.

Comment: Table has 1 row for billing address and 1 row for shipping address and you want the query to return as 1 row?

Comment: Your query looks wrong the join should be on addresses.customer_id = customers.customer_id - which should return all address for a customer in n rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same field like,

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name,billing.line1 as 
billing_line_1,billing.line2 as 
billing_line_2,shipping.line1 as shipping_line_1,shipping.line2 as shipping_line_2  FROM customers 
JOIN addresses AS shipping ON customers.shipping_address_id = shipping.address_id 
JOIN addresses AS billing ON 
customers.billing_address_id = billing.address_id
```

The working demo for the query is available in

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61db31/1/0)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61db31/1/0

Comment: yes but it returns both shipping and billing address same while they are stored separately based with address_id

Comment: @NaveedKhan Have you understand,the logic i have used in this query.i do not run this query,but trying to show the method of writing such a query

Answer (score 1):

You could use alias for that purpose like:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, addresses.line1 AS billing_line_1,addresses.line2 AS shipping_line_1
FROM `addresses` INNER JOIN customers
ON addresses.address_id = customers.customer_id
```

Here i would get column name with alias defined after "AS". So in above example addresses.line1 column name in output would be billing_line_1 and similarly for addresses.line2 would come as shipping_line_1.

Comment: yes but it returns both shipping and billing address same while they are stored separately based with address_id

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
drop table if exists CustomerAddress;

create table CustomerAddress(id int auto_increment primary key,address_id int, customer_id int, line1 varchar(10),line2 varchar(10));
truncate table CustomerAddress;
insert into CustomerAddress (address_id, customer_id, line1,line2) values
(1,1,'b1_1','b1_2'),(2,1,'s1_1','s1_2'),
(1,2,'b2_1','b2_2'),
(2,3,'s3_1','s3_2');
```

You could use conditional aggregation (aka pivot)

```
SELECT c.customerid, 
         max(case when address_id = 1 then line1 else '' end ) as BillingLine1,
         max(case when address_id = 1 then line2 else '' end ) as BillingLine2,
         max(case when address_id = 2 then line1 else '' end ) as ShippingLine1,
         max(case when address_id = 2 then line2 else '' end ) as ShippingLine2
from customers  c
INNER JOIN Customeraddress a
on a.customer_id = c.Customerid
group by c.customerid;
```

or multiple joins to address

```
SELECT c.customerid,
         a1.line1 as billingline1,a1.line2 as billingline2,
         a2.line1 as shippingline1,a2.line2 as shippingline2
from customers c
left join CustomerAddress a1 on c.customerid = a1.customer_id and a1.address_id = 1
left join CustomerAddress a2 on c.customerid = a2.customer_id and a2.address_id = 2
where a1.address_id is not null or a2.address_id is not null
order by c.customerid
;
```

As to which is best run explain and examine the results. BTW you should drive this from customer not from address.